# modify the redirection after confirming the order in prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

How I can modify the redirection after confirming the order from history to my account?
I do not know where I can change the code.

I modified the code of the OrderConfirmationController.php page in the overide:

```
if (Cart::isGuestCartByCartId($this->id_cart)) {
    $is_guest = true;
    $redirectLink = 'index.php?controller=guest-tracking';
} else {
    $redirectLink = 'index.php?controller=history';
}
```

By:

```
 if (Cart::isGuestCartByCartId($this->id_cart)) {
            $is_guest = true;
            $redirectLink = 'index.php?controller=guest-tracking';
        } else {
            $redirectLink = 'index.php?controller=my-account';
        }
```

and I deleted class_index.php located in the cache folder and still I have the same problem the redirection is to the history

Comment: How can we advise on modifying something that we don't see? Please describe the current and the desirable behaviour and the relevant bits of code (see [mcve]). If you don't know what code is relevant then at least tell us how to reproduce the issue

Comment: also please do not use tags with "DO NOT USE IT" in the description

Answer (score 0):

You have to override orderConfirmationController.php

[Read this document](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors?_ga=2.135732982.611486393.1537523655-246929394.1501847074#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingacontroller)